# Fody weaving - should I include dlls from referenced project as well?

Tags: c#, console-application, fody, fody-costura

I have a 'service' csproj that has references to topshelf (to make this as windows service), quartz (for scheduling) and a reference to my 'core' csproj where my actual code is. I use costura to merge all dlls to make into one final exe.

I have topshelf, quartz and core as IncludedAssemblies in my FodyWeavers.xml. And the final exe have these embedded too. Checked with 'dotpeek'. However, when I execute the exe, it just says 'service is now running, press Control+C to exit.'. It did not reach my actual code which is in core project.

After trying a lot of things, I copied the dlls that my core project reference to the output folder and then the service started running - executing my code and making db updates, writing logs etc.

So I tried to mention the nuget package dlls and project references dlls of 'core' too in fodyweavers.xml but then I got build error saying 'Assembly cannot be found, not even as copylocal=false'

Can somebody please hint me in the right direction? Maybe, I am missing something obvious.